# Define platform specific app ID in tiapp.xml?

Tags: cross-platform, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, app-distribution

I am completely rebuilding an old Titanium app for my company in the Alloy MVC framework and distributing to iOS & Android. The app IDs are different for each respective platforms' marketplace for some reason and I want to use the same, old IDs so that current users of the old app will get notified of a new version. I'm getting closer to distribution and wanted to know if I am able to specify a different app ID to use in the `tiapp.xml` of my project for each platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply NO, you cannot specify platform specific app id in single build. Recently I had also faced exact same situation, and the only solution was to change the app id while building for each platform...

**OR**

Dump your old app & create a new one if you don't care about previous app id much, but as you said that users should be notify of the newer version, then your only option is what I mentioned above. After all, it's a very small task to change app id before creating distribution builds.

Good Luck!

Comment: Hoping for a better solution, but thank you! The id is the same on iOS thankfully so I don't have to setup another certificate, altering the ID on Android before distribution should be simple enough.

Comment: Yeah, changing id carefully is just a matter of few seconds and care-ness. :)